# Result attached or exception

Tags: eiffel, void-safety

Let's say that I have a function `f` which should return an `attached T` by calling `g`. However, `g` returns a `detachable T`. If `g` results in a Void, I want to raise an exception like this:

```
f: T
  do
    if attached g as res then
      Result := res
    else
      raise
    end
  end
  
raise
  do
    (create {DEVELOPER_EXCEPTION}).raise
  end
```

In this setup EiffelStudio gives me an error `VEVI: Variable is not properly set. Variable: Result` at the end of `f`.

Indeed, Result can be Void at the end of `f` but the execution should not reach the end of `f` in this case, an exception should have been raised.

How can I restructure the code to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type of a raised exception does not matter, the following code will do:

```
f: T
    do
        Result := g
        check is_g_attached: attached Result then end
    end
```

If the type of the raised exception is important, the feature `raise` can be augmented with the postcondition `False` that indicates that the feature never returns. Then, the code would look like

```
f: T
    do
        Result := g
        if not attached Result then
            raise
        end
    end

raise
    do
        (create {DEVELOPER_EXCEPTION}).raise
    ensure
        False
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that `check`s can be used in this case:

```
f: T
  do
    if attached g as res then
      Result := res
    else
      raise
    end
    check attached Result then end
  end
```

However, I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: I think removing a `check` should never trigger a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away with:

```
f:T
   do
      check has_g: attached g then Result := g end
   end
```

The code will naturally break if the check-condition `attached g` is not `True`. Note that I use this construct quite a bit when I want to ensure that a feature like `g` is attached.

I will also code it as:

```
f:T
   do
      check has_g: attached g as al_result then Result := al_result end
   end
```

So, you might ask: How is this different and what is the "al_" prefix about?

1. The first example doesn't have the `as ____` clutter, which makes it easier to read and comprehend (IMHO).
2. The "al_" prefix is a naming convention I follow, where "al" means "attachment local". As a reader of my code, I can then look at the variable name and know where the variable was declared.

- If the variable has no prefix, then it is a feature reference on the class itself.
- If the prefix is "l_?", then I look to the feature `local`
  declarations.
- If "al_", then I look to a `check` or `if .. then` or other block for an `as` keyword.
- I also use this for across loops, where `ic_?` is an "Iteration Cursor" local object. I use this naming convention applied to symbolic loops as well.